# Mysql with express query returns null

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I use express on server side. 
Here is the code:

```
// router
const database = require('../services/database-service');

router.get('/allreviews', function (req, res, next) {
    let reviewsSql =
        'select r.reviewId, r.username, r.time, r.reviewText, r.visit, ri.fileName ' +
        'from (select min(reviewImgId) as imgId, reviewId ' +
        'from ReviewImgs ' +
        'group by reviewId) img, Reviews r, ReviewImgs ri ' +
        'where img.imgId=ri.reviewImgId and ri.reviewId=r.reviewId;';

    database.query(reviewsSql, function (result) {
        console.log(result);   // NULL
        res.send(result);
    });
});

// database-service.js
const mysql=require('mysql');

module.exports = {
    query: function (sql, data, fn) {
        const connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host     : '127.0.0.1',
            user     : 'root',
            password : 'xxxxxxxxx',
            database : 'Movie',
            port:'3306'
        });

        connection.connect();

        connection.query(sql, data, function (error, result) {
            if (error){
                console.log(error);
                return;
            }

            fn(result);
        });

        connection.end();
    }
};
```

The problem is that the query result is always null. However, I execute the sql query code in mysql command line, and the result is a set containing 3 rows, which is exactly what I want. So what's happening?

Comment: Get rid off the old ANSI comma join which is over 25 year old and use proper `INNER JOIN` syntax.. Besides your misusing MySQL extended GROUP BY feature which can cause invalid results this is very common mistake on MySQL https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: This is a piece of good advice! Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
// database-service.js
const mysql=require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host     : '127.0.0.1',
            user     : 'root',
            password : 'xxxxxxxxx',
            database : 'Movie',
            port:'3306'
        });

connection.connect();

module.exports = connection;
```

//To execute your query

```
 database.query(reviewsSql, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);   // NULL
        res.send(result);
    });
```

Comment: I did this. And I just found the real problem! I should do this: database.query(reviewsSql, null function).... The second parameter cannot be missing!

Answer (score 0):

*classical*  callbacks for asynchronous libraries are in general in the form `function(err, result)`, but you pass `function (result)`

JavaScript does not care how the parameters are called, the callback will receive the error es first argument. So the `result` parameter actually holds the `err` because its the first argument, and that being `null` means that there is no error.

So just change `function (result)` to `function(err, result)`